# ng-animate and jquery slideUp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an ng animation but it seems to not work well, this is what I have :

```
app
.animation('notification-enter', ['$timeout',function($timeout) {
  return {
    setup : function(element) {
      $(element).addClass('hide');
    },
    start : function(element, done, memo) {
      $(element).slideDown();
    },
    cancel : function(element, done) {
    }
  };
}])
.animation('notification-leave', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    setup : function(element) {
    },
    start : function(element, done, memo) {
      // at this moment, the item is removed so we cannot do the slideUp effect.
      $(element).slideUp();
    },
    cancel : function(element, done) {
    }
  };
}]);
```

I don't know if this is a proper way to implement the effect with ngAnimate. In the code above, I only have the problem when I remove an item, in `start()` function, the item is already removed.

**So the question is how to implement the item removal with `slideUp()` effect properly with ngAnimate ?**

Comment: Try to use the ng-animate directive, with AngularJS 1.1.5. This site has some samples: [ng-animate samples](http://http://www.nganimate.org/)

Comment: @BrunoCroysFelthes the example above already uses ng-animate :)